# Can you help me identify this serif? It closely resembles with "Shaolin Style" and "Freight Big Pro"

Tags: font-identification

I tried both Whatthefont.com and whatfontis.com but couldn't find the right font.
It will be very helpful it you could provide a free alternative if this is not free.

[image]

Also there are many fonts like these (having that much contrast) Is there a special name for these fonts?

I know most people here don't like these type of questions but it will be very kind if you can help me out in this, plus isn't this font too awesome?

Much thanks.

Comment: Nice font! Less keen on the `c` but love the `y` and `v`. I don't know any name for this type of font, but one term for how much variation there is in the weight of a font is **contrast** (so you could call this a [super-high contrast serif](http://typophile.com/node/74537) but maybe it's more than that?). More info at [How can I describe the font I am looking for or looking at?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-can-i-describe-the-font-i-am-looking-for-or-looking-at)

Comment: @user568458  I didn't know the term "contrast". Thanks for increasing my knowledge! :)

Comment: It maybe a custom variation of "Freight Big Pro" for that headline maybe but I am not so sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Dala Floda](https://commercialtype.com/typefaces/dala_floda/dala_floda/roman_no_2) Roman #2 by Commercial Type

[image]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the font.