# I need a font like this but don't know which terms to look for

Tags: fonts, font-identification, resource-recommendations

I have an idea for a logo, and an idea of what the font should look like. However, I don't know how to go about describing that to find a font.

I know that the lines of the S should be parallel as well as a few other features, but don't know how I'd translate that into a search. The usual parameters of font categorisation don't cover this.

Attached a drawing of what I'm thinking, so if anyone happens to know a similar font to get me going that would be great (it should be heavier than this but this shape).

[image: Like this but thicker]

Comment: You don't need to design the typeface, just 5 letters, and the top half of the 'r' shape can be used in all of them (rotate, reflect, etc)

Comment: I think the op would like a font to match his logo (?) A quick search gave me UWR Nissan... not sure using a font designed for a particular car brand is a good idea! Another thing that might be helpful is to have a look at the "similar" fonts on myfonts.com on the top right http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/nissan/  It doesn't come in a light weight, anyway

Comment: For a logo it may be best to design the art yourself, since you have already sketched it out the hard part is done.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate): [How can I describe the font I am looking for or looking at?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/how-can-i-describe-the-font-i-am-looking-for-or-looking-at/29281#29281)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

johnp [already mentioned](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/65509/8708) using an automated font identification tool might prove troublesome without a rendered sample, but you could always just make your own rendered sample. It doesn't have to be perfect since the auto-identifiers build in some tolerance to broaden the search. Luckily, your glyphs are easy enough to create:

[image: smarta type sample]

[WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) returns a few typefaces that are very similar to your sample.

[image: Snasm ExtraLight type sample] [image: Hemi Head type sample]

[image: Elevon type sample] [image: Korataki type sample]

Another auto-identification service is [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/).

Answer (score 24):

If you are looking for a font which specific features, I would recommend using font identification apps/sites based on the traits you have in mind. In your case, it would be helpful to upload your final logotype to online ID sites to find something similar.

1. [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/identify.html) is a useful tool to find a typeface based on some questions on a font's anatomy.
2. Using this together with MyFont's "similar" font suggestions can be helpful. MyFonts also provides a [font identification](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) app and site, though this may not be helpful in your case, unless you provide a rendered prototype.
3. [Fontspring](http://www.fontspring.com/matcherator) also has a font id site in beta.
4. If you see a typeface with similar characteristics in the wild web, [Fount](https://fount.artequalswork.com/) can help identify it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a close match, but I wouldn't recommend using the Nissan font! @bboybeatle

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to try a decent FREE font exchange go to http://www.dafont.com/. You can type in the actual letters you want to see in the fonts they have listed. They have it grouped very well and it may take a few minutes but I think you'll find what you want, be able to download and install quickly and be on your way.

Try the "Techno" section first.

Where it says Preview - enter "smarta" in the case you want.

Fonts work well on PC and Mac.

Comment: "decent" is a bit of a subjective term :) (I will admit, there are some good typefaces on DaFont, but also a lot of crap...so be selective!)

Comment: Worth noting you should always check the actual licence on any font you find there, a lot will say free when what they are is free for personal use.